# Oracle and Sybase compatibility for create table new_table as

Tags: sql, oracle, sybase

I am trying to write an SQL query which needs to be compatible on both a Sybase and Oracle database. The query looks like the following :

```
SELECT * 
  INTO new_table
  FROM other_table
```

This query is working great on a Sybase database but not on an Oracle one. I found the equivalent for Oracle :

```
CREATE table new_table AS
SELECT * 
  FROM other_table
```

Is there a way to write a third query that would do the same and that can be executed on a Sybase and on an Oracle database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you found, Oracle supports `INTO` but doesn't use it like Sybase/SQL Server do.  Likewise, Sybase doesn't support Oracle's extension of the `CREATE TABLE` syntax.

The most reliable means of creating a table & importing data between the systems is to use two statements:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table (
  ...columns...
)

INSERT INTO new_table
SELECT * 
  FROM OLD_TABLE
```

Even then, syntax is different because Oracle requires each statement to be delimited by a semi-colon when TSQL doesn't.

Creating a table & importing all the data from another table is a red flag to me - This is not something you'd do in a stored procedure for a production system.  TSQL and PLSQL are very different, so I'd expect separate scripts for DML changes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no query that would do what you want. These environments are very different.

Comment: Ok. And knowing that I need to build a new table depending on the results of a query, do you think there is a query that would work for these 2 environments?

Comment: @MartinMoizard Yes it ends by adding a DUAL table to the sql-server databases, which some fool copies back to to Oracle hiding the system pseudo table. Finally you have more than one row in Dual.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible.

```
SELECT * INTO new_table FROM existing_table;
```

Thanks